# Failing to disable a Get-wmiobject win32_NetworkAdapter via PowerShell (dell venue 8 pro) (windows10)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to reproduce the instructions of https://github.com/vstarostenko/dv8p_wifi_issue_fix/blob/master/README.md
But while everything seems correct, the system is just not following orders (which is to disable the network adapter). It runs a windows10 system, I didn't try with the previous version.

What I've done:

1. Open PowerShell as administrator
2. Run "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"
3. Run "Get-wmiobject win32_NetworkAdapter". Then I get that my device has an ID of 1
4. Write and execute the script:

*Using the first line or the second doesn't make any difference

```
#$adapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | where {$_.DeviceID -eq 1}
$adapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -computerName LocalHost -filter "DeviceId = 1"
$adapter.Availability
$adapter.Disable()
$adapter.Availability
```

Then I get an unchanged status, precisely this

```
3

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   : 

3
```

From what I've read, this should work. What's failing?

[SOLVED]
Not knowing why it doesn't work, I have done it in the following way:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi | fl Status
Get-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi | Disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false
Get-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi | fl Status
Get-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi | Enable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false
Get-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi | fl Status
```

Comment: Why not use `Disable-NetAdapter`?

Comment: I will try it (just reading the docs). But if my code is not working, why should your option work? Or in other words, why is the posted code not working?

Comment: I have done it and it works, but I cannot mark it as solved in the comments. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

`Availablity` doesn't specify enabled/disabled, but if the network adapter is available, ex. not working, not enough Power, no driver(i think).

`NetEnabled` specifies if the network adapter is enabled/in use (will show false on enabled wifi if not Connected to network).

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't turn off the device. I have done it through Disable-NetAdapter and now it turns off and on the device